# Find how many times one array it's included in another C++

Tags: c++

I need a code that finds how many times one array fits inside another.The user would input the size of both arrays and their values.
The output should look like this:

```
***enter size of first array:***
11
***enter first array values:***  
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
***enter size of second array:*** 
3
***enter second array values:***  
1 2 1
***result: 5 times***
```

And that's part of the code I came out with:

```
int v1Size = 5;
int v2Size = 3;

int vector1[] = {1,2,1,2,1};
int vector2[] = {1,2,1};

int counter = 0;


bool contain(int v1Pos) {

    int j = 0;
    int i = v1Pos;
    int check = 0;
    while ((j < v2Size) || (i < v1Size-v2Size)) {
        for (int i; i < v1Size-v2Size; i++) {
            if(vector2[j] == vector1[i]) {
                check++;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (check == v2Size) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main(){

    for(int i = 0; i < v1Size; i++) {
        if(contain(i)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << counter << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, I defined the arrays to simplify debugging, but it should work to every arrays: size of vector1 < 500 and size of vector2 < 100.

Anyone have an idea how could I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at string search algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: What is the exact issue you're having?

Comment: You have 2 int i; and one of them is uninitialized. Try turning on compiler warnings, and *fix them*.

Comment: The code has undefined behavior because of the uninitialized variable in the for loop. Usually the program will get stuck in an endless loop because `i` will contain values bigger than `v1Size-v2Size` but the program won't leave the outer `while` loop.

Comment: After you fixed the first problem I mentioned, you will stay in the endless loop, because you only increment `j` if you have a match. You need to find a solution for the case, where `vector2[j] == vector1[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Check at each position of `vector1`, if that position contains the whole `vector2`. If yes,  increment `count`. Increment position.

A pseudo code

```
init count with 0
init pos1 with 0
while pos1 < v1Size - v2Size
    init pos2 with 0
    init match with true
    while pos2 < v2Size
        if vector1[pos1 + pos2] not equals vector2[pos2]
            set match = false
            break while loop
    if match
        increment count
    increment pos1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::search`.

```
int main()
{
int v1Size = 5;
int v2Size = 3;

int vector1[] = {1,2,1,2,1};
int * v1End = vector1 + v1Size;
int vector2[] = {1,2,1};
int * v2End = vector2 + v2Size;

int counter = 0;
for (int * p = vector1; p != v1End; ++p) {
    counter += (std::search(p, v1End, vector2, v2End) == p);
}

std::cout << counter << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: main.cpp:22:23: error: expected expression
    auto containsV2 = [=](int * p){
It gives an error in the [=].

Comment: I was being too clever. Just using search in a loop is much easier to get right

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using int arrays, you should use `std::vector<int>` type, which can have any size.

Then, you can use [std::search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) to search for vector in a vector.

Comment: It has to be an array. It's part of the exercise... But thanks anyways.

Comment: Thanks for saying my answer is useless ... You didn't say it has to be an 
`int[] `. If you need dynamic size array, you have to allocate it on heap with `new []`, but honestly, we use containers in C++.

Comment: You can use `std::search` with C arrays fine. A pointer which points into an array (including one past the end) is a ForwardIterator